# Express: push element in an model's array

Tags: javascript, express

i have this model:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        userName: {type: String, required: true},
        firstName: {type: String},
        lastName: {type: String},
        password: {type: String, required: true},
        email: {type: String},
        profileImg: String,
        weight: {type:Array, default:[]},
        schedules: {type: [schedule], default: []},
        dateCreated: {type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now},
    }
);
```

As you can see i have a field 'weight' that must contains numbers, when i try to do a put and push a new number inside it i have some strange behavior, this is the server side:

```
  var data = req.body;
    var _id = req.params.userid.replace(new RegExp('"', 'g'), "")
    User.findById(_id, fieldsFilter, function (err, user) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        console.log('*********', data.weight)

        if (user) {
            user.userName = data.userName ? data.userName : user.userName;
            user.firstName = data.firstName ? data.firstName : user.firstName;
            user.lastName = data.lastName ? data.lastName : user.lastName;
            user.email = data.email ? data.email : user.email;
            //TODO check if weight is in correct form
            // HERE!!
            user.weight = data.weight ? user.weight.push( data.weight) : user.weight;
            user.save(onModelSave(res));
            console.log(user.weight)
        } else {
            //user does not exist create it
            var newUser = new User(data);
            newUser._id = ObjectId(req.params.userid);
            newUser.save(onModelSave(res, 201, true));
        }
```

As you can see i have two console log and data.weight has a value of `5`, this is the output of the prints:

```
********* 5
[1]
```

So in the array it stores 1? 
I cannot understand where the problem is.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is `console.log(user.weight)` before the push line?

Comment: @epascarello is an empty array: []

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
user.weight = data.weight ? user.weight.push( data.weight) : user.weight;
```

If `data.weight` exists, you assign to `user.weight` the result of `user.weight.push()`. Which is the [*new length of the array*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) (which is 1, if `user.weight` was previously empty).

It looks like you want this:

```
if (data.weight) {
  user.weight.push(data.weight);
}
```